# MySQL Trigger/Procedure Not Working

Tags: mysql

I have a trigger and procedure that should generate invoice number.

Examples of numbers (format: type/number/month/year):

```
VAT/5/05/2011
VAT/6/05/2011
VAT/7/06/2011
```

When inserting invoice with `year = YEAR(CURDATE())` it should only increase number integer.

But, when inserting invoice with new year (on 1st of Jan) it should generate new invoice number, and this part of my system is not working.

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  generate_vat_number(out InvoiceNumber VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            SPLIT_STR(Number, '/', 1),
            '/',
            COUNT(Number) + 1,
            '/',
            SPLIT_STR(Number, '/', 3),
            '/',
            YEAR(CURDATE())
        )
        INTO InvoiceNumber
    FROM Invoices
    WHERE
        SPLIT_STR(Number, '/', 4) = YEAR(CURDATE())
    LIMIT 1;
END$$
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_invoice_number BEFORE INSERT ON Invoices
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    CALL generate_vat_number(@out);
    IF @out = NULL THEN
        SET NEW.Number = CONCAT(SPLIT_STR(NEW.Number, '/', 1), '/', '1', '/', SPLIT_STR(NEW.Number, '/', 3), '/', YEAR(CURDATE()));
    ELSE
        SET NEW.Number =  @out;
    END IF;
END$$
```

Function used to split strings:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

When I try to create new invoice I get error saying that Number field cannot be null, which is true. I'm changing my operating system year to simulate year changes. According to this, I presume that my trigger is not working correctly. However, I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I can see only one issue in your trigger, try using `@out IS NULL` instead of `@out = NULL`.

Corrected trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_invoice_number BEFORE INSERT ON Invoices
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    CALL generate_vat_number(@out);
    IF @out IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.Number = CONCAT(SPLIT_STR(NEW.Number, '/', 1), '/', '1', '/', SPLIT_STR(NEW.Number, '/', 3), '/', YEAR(CURDATE()));
    ELSE
        SET NEW.Number =  @out;
    END IF;
END$$
```

Let us know if that works for you.